# Basic socket.io - node.js communication

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following setup using node.js and socket.io :

Client :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No title</title>    
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('init', function() {
            console.log('Hello world !');
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Server :

```
const https = require('https');

var port    = 80,
    http    = require('http'),
    app     = require('express')(),
    server  = require('http').Server(app),
    io      = require('socket.io')(server),
    CronJob = require('cron').CronJob,
    fs      = require('fs');

// ...

io.on('connection', function(client) {

    console.log('User connected.');
    client.emit('init');

    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('User disconnected.');
    });

});
```

Do you have any idea why I haven't any message (apart from 'User connected.' and 'User disconnected.') in the server or browser log ? I guess it is something trivial but I can't find what...

Thanks !

EDIT :

I added this :

Client :

```
socket.emit('hello');
```

Server :

```
io.on('hello', function() {
    console.log('Hello world !');
});
```

It does not work either...

EDIT 2 :

```
server.listen(port);
register('Express', 'Listening on port', port);

app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
    res.sendFile( root + '/index.html' );
});

app.get( '/*', function(req, res, next) {
    var file = req.params[0]; 
    register('File requested', file);
    res.sendFile( root + '/' + file );
});
```

Comment: What happens if you change `client.emit` to `io.emit(..);` (on the server), does it work then?

Comment: Hmm... Yes. Where does the problem come from ?

Comment: It should work, I found this example - `io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
});`, can you try this and see if it works?

Comment: I edited my post. There is another problem with a client emitter and the server listener, even with a io object instead of client.

Comment: How do you serve your html, and how do you listen? You get `User connected.`?

Comment: I use Express. I updated my post.

Comment: `io.on('hello', ...)` on the server should be `client.on('hello', ...)`.

Comment: Yes, but it does not work either. It is what I did first.

Comment: @Arbuste try this example: https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example

Comment: @bolav Thank you for the example. I did not found what was wrong in my code, but I wrote it again, and now it works.